# How to avoid duplicate name while creating Sitecore item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I'm facing a problem in my Sitecore project. As we are working in a team, we can't track all the item who has created and what name they have given. The problem is, people are creating the item with same name. This is causing some serious problem while moving the items to different environments.

What I want is, while creating the Sitecore item,  pipeline method should execute and validate whether its immediate parent already has the same item name.

For example : `Parent A` has 3 subitems called `Child1, Child2, Child3`, when developer tried to create a item with name `Child2` the popup/alert should display and not to allow him to create the item.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 12):

You can add your own handler to `item:creating` event and check if the parent already contains a child with proposed name.

Here is nice post describing [how to prevent duplicates items in Sitecore](https://sitecoreclimber.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/prevent-duplicates-items/). I've copied the following code from there:

```xml
<event name="item:creating">
  <handler type="YourNameSpace.PreventDuplicates, YourAssembly" method="OnItemCreating" />
</event>
```

```cs
namespace YourNamespace
{
  public class PreventDuplicates
  {
    public void OnItemCreating(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      using (new SecurityDisabler())
      {
        ItemCreatingEventArgs arg = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as ItemCreatingEventArgs;

        if ((arg != null) && (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name == "shell"))
        {
          foreach (Item currentItem in arg.Parent.GetChildren())
          {
            if ((arg.ItemName.Replace(' ', '-').ToLower() == currentItem.Name.ToLower()) 
              && (arg.ItemId != currentItem.ID))
            {
              ((SitecoreEventArgs)args).Result.Cancel = true;
              Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert
                ("Name " + currentItem.Name + " is already in use.Please use another name for the page.");
              return;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That solution doesn't catch problems from renaming items, it only checks when an Item is created.

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post out for this which uses the item create / save event and uses index search to identify duplicates. This was implemented and tested with Sitecore 7.2. Here's the config used:

```
<sitecore>
  <events>
    <event name="item:creating">
      <handler type="MySite.Customizations.Customized_Sitecore.UniqueItemNameValidator, MySite" method="OnItemCreating" />
    </event>
    <event name="item:saving">
      <handler type="MySite.Customizations.Customized_Sitecore.UniqueItemNameValidator, MySite" method="OnItemSaving" />
    </event>
  </events>
</sitecore>
```